# Splitting column with text data without delimiters into individual columns

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

My dataset is in dataframe (df1):

[image]

want to split the event_type field in above df1 into individual columns for each of the letters that are up to 20 columns with each column holding a single letter;

What I have tried in Pandas which works:

```
import pandas as pd
df2 = df1.toPandas()
df3 = df2.head().event_type.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list(x), index=[['step_'+str(col) for col in np.arange(0, 20, 1)]]))
```

[image]

Issues:

- When I remove head() to apply the formula to the entire column event_type, I get an error in the length
  of the of passed values (ValueError: Length of passed values is 11, index implies 20)
- I also want all three original columns from the main dataframe df1 into the final dataframe df3, along with the split values

Final Dataset should look like:

[image]

Tried:

```
df2 = df1.event_type.str.split('', expand=True)
df2.head()
```

Final Code That worked:

```
df2 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df1.event_type.map(list).tolist()).add_prefix('step'), df1.event_type], axis =1)
```

Merging it back with original dataframe:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how = 'inner', on = ['event_type'])
```

Final O/P: `df3.head()`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the spark column split function.

```
df  = df.withColumn('len', length('event_type'))
df2 = df.withColumn('temp', rpad('event_type', 20, ' ')) \
  .select(*df.columns, *map(lambda i: split('temp', '|')[i].alias('step_' + str(i+1)), range(0, 20))) \
  .drop('temp')

df2.show(10, False)

+---+-----------------+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|id |event_type       |len|step_1|step_2|step_3|step_4|step_5|step_6|step_7|step_8|step_9|step_10|step_11|step_12|step_13|step_14|step_15|step_16|step_17|step_18|step_19|step_20|
+---+-----------------+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|1  |asdferwafaryt    |13 |a     |s     |d     |f     |e     |r     |w     |a     |f     |a      |r      |y      |t      |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
|2  |aweraadsf        |9  |a     |w     |e     |r     |a     |a     |d     |s     |f     |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
|3  |adsfwelklkjasdklj|17 |a     |d     |s     |f     |w     |e     |l     |k     |l     |k      |j      |a      |s      |d      |k      |l      |j      |       |       |       |
|4  |adlflkjwelkj     |12 |a     |d     |l     |f     |l     |k     |j     |w     |e     |l      |k      |j      |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |       |
|5  |lafelkjcfpoiucz  |15 |l     |a     |f     |e     |l     |k     |j     |c     |f     |p      |o      |i      |u      |c      |z      |       |       |       |       |       |
+---+-----------------+---+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: I think you can omit the `|` in the split function.

Comment: I tried the above code ran into error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-1023737>", line 1
    df5 = df4.withColumn('temp', rpad('event_type', 20, ' '))   .select(*df4.columns, *map(lambda i: split('temp', '|')[i].alias('step_' + str(i+1)), range(0, 20)))   .drop('temp')

Comment: I was able to make the code work another way, see answer in my original comment at the bottom, but would like to understand why your method is throwing an error, if you have any direction.

Comment: Too short info, I cannot debug your code. Anyway, this is pure pyspark code and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try `map` and construct dataframe and add `add_prefix`

Sample `df`:

```
Out[26]:
   id             event_type
0   0                  cfaac
1   1                  fdceb
2   2    cdceeedaffcbaefeefa
3   3                 cbccbe
4   4            ecfcffddbad
5   5                   eebd
6   6  eecffbcbaffcbfecceffe
7   7      abdaadacdeeaaaceb
8   8      ceadfacedfbbbaceb
9   9          bbbcfaacbffdf

pd.DataFrame(df.event_type.map(list).tolist()).add_prefix('step')

Out[25]:
  step0 step1 step2 step3 step4 step5 step6 step7 step8 step9 step10 step11  \
0     c     f     a     a     c  None  None  None  None  None   None   None
1     f     d     c     e     b  None  None  None  None  None   None   None
2     c     d     c     e     e     e     d     a     f     f      c      b
3     c     b     c     c     b     e  None  None  None  None   None   None
4     e     c     f     c     f     f     d     d     b     a      d   None
5     e     e     b     d  None  None  None  None  None  None   None   None
6     e     e     c     f     f     b     c     b     a     f      f      c
7     a     b     d     a     a     d     a     c     d     e      e      a
8     c     e     a     d     f     a     c     e     d     f      b      b
9     b     b     b     c     f     a     a     c     b     f      f      d

  step12 step13 step14 step15 step16 step17 step18 step19 step20
0   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None
1   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None
2      a      e      f      e      e      f      a   None   None
3   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None
4   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None
5   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None
6      b      f      e      c      c      e      f      f      e
7      a      a      c      e      b   None   None   None   None
8      b      a      c      e      b   None   None   None   None
9      f   None   None   None   None   None   None   None   None
```

Answer (score 0):

try `df2 = df1.event_type.str.split('', expand=True)`

then merge the result with the other ("id", "len") columns.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply; this doesn't work have tried it, I think it works if there is a space between two words; it doesn't work in my use case

Comment: strange. I just tested it  - splits words by letter. There is nothing between the 2 quotes in `split('', expand=True)` pls check and try again.

Comment: I tried again, I have added the screen shot towards the end of my original question above. I am running this in databricks not sure if that would have any impact, its still in python though.